# Python: Write to new file line

Tags: windows, python

I have been looking around to see if I can find a way to write to a new line in a file every time the user inputs.
The basic code is this:

```
while True:
f = open(server,"w")
initchat = str(input("Chat: "))
chat = str((user + " - " + initchat))
f.write(chat)
f.write("\n")
f.close
```

Many of the answers have been to add \n to the string but that only adds a new line after and doesn't allow the new line to be written to. Do I make any sense?
Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: "Do I make any sense?" - Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while True:
    f = open(server ,"a")  #changed so data will be appended rather than wrote to the file
    initchat = str(input("Chat: "))
    chat = str((user + " - " + initchat))
    f.write(chat + "\n")
    f.close
```